# is there a way to find the local directory of the file instead of its $_FILES[''][tmp_name] in php

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch an image from a local directory and would love to allow the user a preview before uploading the picture to the server;
so my question is will I be able to extract the exact directory of the image from the $_FILES variable instead of its "tmp_name" since I could not use the "tmp_name" value as src=" " for the HTML "IMG" tag;

thanks in advance!

Comment: When you upload an image from a web form, this image gets uploaded to the server and php saves it in the temporary directory provided by `tmp_name`. You need to use `move_uploaded_file` to move the temporary file inside your webserver directory so that it can be used in the SRC of your HTML

Comment: The phrase “before uploading the picture to the server” really implies client side which is [really easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/231316). Otherwise, you need to handle uploads normally in PHP, but you could handle the preview with AJAX